# Is it risky to store public and private keys together in pkcs12?

Tags: cryptography, pkcs#12, truststore

I have recently been working with some `p12` files storing both private and public keys.  Being far from a cryptography expert, I started pondering whether storing a public and private key being stored together in the same archive (and then transferred over wire) defeats the whole purpose of the keys.

Comment: can you explain when you are transferring things?  you should certainly NOT given anyone your private key.  it's meant to be private.  what files are you talking about?  are these in a config for ssl or something?  are you actually doing the transferring or just assuming that is what happens?

Comment: in our package repository we have a p12 file that is used in product deployment and that file has both the private and public keys.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong storing a public key along with the private key in a file. It all depends on the intent of this.

If you only wanted to send the public key to a third party, then by sending your private key you give them a way to break the public key mechanism. This is insecure, and you should throw away your keys as have they don't have any values now.

If the transfer is part of your infrastructure, **and** the transfer happens securely, **and** you fully expect this file to be private on the destination, then there's nothing wrong storing them as one file.

Most frameworks will know how to use a single private/public file properly, and would only disclose the public part to a third party and keep the private part internal.

Answer (score 1):

Whether to distribute private keys or not depends on your particular needs. Normally they are kept secret and not distributed more than needed (almost never).

Technically it's possible to add a certificate without a private key into PKCS#12 container, but this doesn't make much sense because other formats are more practical for distributing just certificates. And if you are adding a private key just because some software works only with PKCS#12 format and you don't know how to avoid putting the private key there, this is a mistake - you should not do this.

Now, safety of data in PKCS#12 file depends on what encryption algorithm is used. Previously (in older versions of Windows) 40-bit encryption was used by default. 40-bit is not secure, that's for sure. Newer versions support 3DES encryption - it's much stronger.